# Static assertion failure when compiling GStreamer 1.24.0

Tags: c, gstreamer, glib, meson-build

I'm using `mingw32` to compile GStreamer 1.24.0 but it fails with the following error:

```
In file included from D:/msys64/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9,
                 from D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:34,
                 from D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:34,
                 from D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:32,
                 from D:/msys64/mingw32/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:27,
                 from D:/msys64/mingw32/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/rtp/gstrtpbuffer.h:27,
                 from ../gst/rtp/gstrtpac3pay.c:42:
../gst/rtp/gstrtpac3pay.c: In function 鈥?[01mgst_rtp_ac3_pay_get_type鈥?
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:870:31: error: static assertion failed: "Expression evaluates to false"
  870 | #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) _Static_assert (expr, "Expression evaluates to false")
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:260:5: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mG_STATIC_ASSERT鈥?  260 |     G_STATIC_ASSERT (sizeof *(location) == sizeof (gpointer));       \
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2294:7: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mg_once_init_enter鈥? 2294 |   if (g_once_init_enter (&static_g_define_type_id)) \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2326:3: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01m_G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN_REGISTER鈥? 2326 |   _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN_REGISTER(TypeName, type_name, TYPE_PARENT, flags) \
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2045:61: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01m_G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN鈥? 2045 | #define G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED(TN, t_n, T_P, _f_, _C_)      _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN (TN, t_n, T_P, _f_) {_C_;} _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTE
NDED_END()
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:1826:61: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mG_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED鈥? 1826 | #define G_DEFINE_TYPE(TN, t_n, T_P)                         G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED (TN, t_n, T_P, 0, {})
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../gst/rtp/gstrtpac3pay.c:84:1: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mG_DEFINE_TYPE鈥?   84 | G_DEFINE_TYPE (GstRtpAC3Pay, gst_rtp_ac3_pay, GST_TYPE_RTP_BASE_PAYLOAD);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gasyncqueue.h:34,
                 from D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:34:
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:261:17: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  261 |     (void) (0 ? (gpointer) *(location) : NULL);                      \
      |                 ^
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2294:7: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mg_once_init_enter鈥? 2294 |   if (g_once_init_enter (&static_g_define_type_id)) \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2326:3: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01m_G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN_REGISTER鈥? 2326 |   _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN_REGISTER(TypeName, type_name, TYPE_PARENT, flags) \
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2045:61: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01m_G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN鈥? 2045 | #define G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED(TN, t_n, T_P, _f_, _C_)      _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN (TN, t_n, T_P, _f_) {_C_;} _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTE
NDED_END()
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:1826:61: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mG_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED鈥? 1826 | #define G_DEFINE_TYPE(TN, t_n, T_P)                         G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED (TN, t_n, T_P, 0, {})
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../gst/rtp/gstrtpac3pay.c:84:1: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mG_DEFINE_TYPE鈥?   84 | G_DEFINE_TYPE (GstRtpAC3Pay, gst_rtp_ac3_pay, GST_TYPE_RTP_BASE_PAYLOAD);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:870:31: error: static assertion failed: "Expression evaluates to false"
  870 | #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) _Static_assert (expr, "Expression evaluates to false")
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h:128:5: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mG_STATIC_ASSERT鈥?  128 |     G_STATIC_ASSERT (sizeof *(atomic) == sizeof (gpointer));               \
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:262:7: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mg_atomic_pointer_get鈥?  262 |     (!g_atomic_pointer_get (location) &&                             \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2294:7: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mg_once_init_enter鈥? 2294 |   if (g_once_init_enter (&static_g_define_type_id)) \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2326:3: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01m_G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN_REGISTER鈥? 2326 |   _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN_REGISTER(TypeName, type_name, TYPE_PARENT, flags) \
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:2045:61: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01m_G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN鈥? 2045 | #define G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED(TN, t_n, T_P, _f_, _C_)      _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED_BEGIN (TN, t_n, T_P, _f_) {_C_;} _G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTE
NDED_END()
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:1826:61: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mG_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED鈥? 1826 | #define G_DEFINE_TYPE(TN, t_n, T_P)                         G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED (TN, t_n, T_P, 0, {})
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../gst/rtp/gstrtpac3pay.c:84:1: note: in expansion of macro 鈥?[01mG_DEFINE_TYPE鈥?   84 | G_DEFINE_TYPE (GstRtpAC3Pay, gst_rtp_ac3_pay, GST_TYPE_RTP_BASE_PAYLOAD);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/msys64/mingw32/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:870:31: error: static assertion failed: "Expression evaluates to false"
  870 | #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) _Static_assert (expr, "Expression evaluates to false")
```

How do I fix this problem? Is there anything wrong with my meson options?

Comment: There should be a line before or after the one you have posted which says where the problematic part of code actually is.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The line below should indicate where G_STATIC_ASSERT was called from, for example: `filename.c:42:23: note: in expansion of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'`.

Comment: PLease include the complete and exact error message into the question. You can use the `edit` button below your question to add it as formatted text. There must be some information where the `G_STATIC_ASSERT` was used.

Comment: which compiler are you compiling with gcc or mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc  (if you are on win64) ?

Comment: I mistakenly used the compiler and recompiled successfully after installing mingw-w64-i686-toolchain